# Evaluating accuracy of neural network after every epoch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

```
from dataset import get_strange_symbol_loader, get_strange_symbols_test_data
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim


class Net(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28*28, 512)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 15)

def forward(self,x):
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)

    return F.softmax(x, dim=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   net = Net()
   train, test = get_strange_symbol_loader(batch_size=128)
   loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
   optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
   Accuracy = []

   for epoch in range(30):   
       print("epoch",epoch)
       #Train
       for data in train:
           img, label = data  
           net.zero_grad()
           output = net(img.view(-1,28*28))
           loss = F.nll_loss(output, label)
           loss.backward()
           optimizer.step()
       #Test    
       correct, total = 0, 0
       with torch.no_grad():
          for data in test:
               img, label = data
               output = net(img.view(-1,784))
               for idx, i in enumerate(output):
                   if torch.argmax(i) == label[idx]:
                       correct += 1
                       total += 1
       Accuracy.append(round(correct/total, 3))
       print("Accuracy: ",Accuracy)
```

Here is my neural network made with PyTorch based on the one by [Sentdex](https://www.youtube.com/user/sentdex). I'm using a dataset given to me by my university course administrators imported by the function `get_strange_symbol_loader(batch_size=128)`.

When I run this code it tells me that accuracy in every epoch is supposed to be `1.0`. However, running the #Test block after the iteration of the for loop containing epoch gives somewhat more realistic results. Why does this happen?

My goal here is to plot testing accuracy against the number of epochs to find the optimal number of epochs for the model before it starts to overfit.

Comment: Please be more specific. Where does the code tell you that "accuracy in every epoch is supposed to be 1.0"? And why does _what_ happen?

Comment: What I mean by that is that running the test block after the for loop over the epochs returns a more believable accuracy like 85% for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing both `correct` and `total` in the block

```
if torch.argmax(i) == label[idx]:
    correct += 1
    total += 1
```

therefore both have always the same value and one divided by the other gives 1.0

Check your intends, I think removing a tab from `total +=1` should do it.

EDIT: I assume that by "after running the #test block after..." you mean you run another snippet which might be different (is correctly intended perhaps)